# How to create a random access file that holds bank account numbes from 0000 to 1000

Tags: c, file, random

I want to create a random access file that holds existing personal bank accounts numbers between 0 and 1000.

So far I have

int ran_acc_num()
{

FILE *rptr; //pointer for file
rptr = fopen("ran_acc_num.txt", "wb");

}

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you say ASAP, your question is less likely to get answered. Right now, your title (and body) are so non-descriptive that the chance of this question getting answered is around 0%.

Comment: Thanks let me edit it a bit

Comment: have u tried to google it ? do you have some initial code that you got stuck with?

Comment: I'm actually stuck and I have googled it but I'm unsure how to generate the random numbers between the given range

Answer (score 1):

In C? First you have to create the file pointer and open the file in write mode.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("filename", "wb");
```

Then iterate an int from 0 to 1000 and write it.

```
for (i=0; i<=1000; i++)
{
    fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
}
fclose(ft);
```

Comment: should be `fclose(fp);`